# C# Special messagebox (or input box)

Tags: c#, vb.net, custom-controls, messagebox

I was wondering if someone knew how to "invoke" this kind of messagebox in C# or VB.NET

[Don't take any notice of what is written in messagebox it's in French ^^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCaeF.png)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Do you want to see a normal messagebox or do you want one where you can input text?

Comment: @MasterXD, maybe you should look at the image provided.

Comment: Ah, it was an image... stupid me. I believe these messageboxes have been specially designed by Microsoft. You'll have to make one yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Task Dialog`. You can find out how to implement them in your WinForms application [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21276/Vista-TaskDialog-Wrapper-and-Emulator).

**EDIT:**

Oh, look, [someone](https://github.com/yadyn/WPF-Task-Dialog) has even created a wrapper to use them in WPF.

Comment: Perfect, thanks alot! I just couldn't find this word :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of a Form in its properties and make it like a message box. Then add on it every item you need in ur "messagebox". When you wanto to show it, simply create a new instance of that form and it will appear. 
Alternatively, check here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/102866-how-to-display-combobox-items-in-message-box/